# AngularJS how to set this to toggle

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have an ng-repeat and within that it is using ng-click and ng-class exactly like this plunker here

http://plnkr.co/edit/TtQNQXOLggs1bsYKNJvx?p=preview

Now this works fine, it sets the class when you click on the item. However I want to set it so if you click on the item again then it will remove the class.

So I tried doing a little if statement to check if it is already = to 'menuItem' then to change it's value but now it does not work at all.

```
 $scope.setActive = function(menuItem) {
 if ($scope.activeMenu = menuItem)
  {
     $scope.activeMenu = 'null';
  }
 else
  {
     $scope.activeMenu = menuItem;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you mean `if ($scope.activeMenu === menuItem)` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because inside the `if` you assigned a value

```
if ($scope.activeMenu = menuItem)
```

insead of checking equality

```
if ($scope.activeMenu == menuItem)
```

Simply replace `=` with `==`

Comment: Thank you so much, dam the typos!!

Comment: If it solves your issues, please add +1 or accept the answer :)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet I'm afraid, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Check whether `activeItem` is the same as `item` then update activeItem to a falsy value

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.menuItems = ['Home', 'Contact', 'About', 'Other'];
  $scope.activeMenu = $scope.menuItems[0];

  $scope.setActive = function(menuItem) {
    $scope.activeMenu = $scope.activeMenu == menuItem ? undefined : menuItem
  }
});
```

```css
.active {

  background: red;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="account-item" ng-repeat='item in menuItems'>
    <div class="account-heading" ng-class="{active : activeMenu === item}">
      <h4 class="account-title">
        <a href="#/Messages" ng-click="setActive(item)"> {{ item }}</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$scope.setActive = function(menuItem) 
{
    if($scope.activeMenu === menuItem)
    {
        $scope.activeMenu = null;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.activeMenu = menuItem;
    }
}
```

See [this updated plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ga2goFxFgzljJ3aerfcJ?p=preview)